# Can we show Sku in shopping cart in magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, sku, checkout-page

I wan to display the sku in the shopping cart.
https://prnt.sc/lYQhd5uqcTo-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your theme add a new file if it doesn't already exist:

`app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml`

and copy the content from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml` and add to above file.

Now,

Find this div: `<div class="product-item-details">` and add this code inside that div:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getItem()->getSku());?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve your customization with two options. @Adarsh Solution is the one way to do it. But If we need any customizations like getting custom table value this needs to do some stuff with our custom module. In this case, we can use the `additional.product.info` handle to do it as below.

create `checkout_cart_index.xml` and include the customized `block` and `.phtml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="additional.product.info">
            <block class="ABCSolutions\AdditionalProInfo\Block\AdditionalProInfo" name="cart_item_add_info" template="ABCSolutions_AdditionalProInfo::cart/additionalinfo.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the `Block` file you can write the customizations as per your logic.

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\AdditionalProInfo\Block; 

/**
 * AdditionalProInfo
 */
class AdditionalProInfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

public function getCustomMethod()
{
    // Do your code here
    return "SKU";
}
     
}
```

And finally, add your custom method in your `.phtml` file.

```
<span>SKU:<?= $block->getCustomMethod(); ?></span>
```

Run the required command and navigate to the cart page.

Please let me know if it is not working.

Happy coding.